# How to insert tooltips in a scatter plot with bqplot

Tags: python, pandas, tooltip, scatter, bqplot

I have a pandas dataframe (df) with 4 columns, named 'name', 'nb', 'a' and 'b', that characterize a person, with his name, his id number ('nb') and some values ('a' and 'b') associated to it.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "name": ["Thomas", "John", "Anna", "Ben", "Arlette"],
    'nb': [1,2,3,4,5],
    "a": [0, 2, 13, 43, 90],
    "b": [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to create a scatter plot with the "a" and "b" values where the name and id would appear inside a tooltip. I think I can do that with the bqplot libary.

I wrote the following code :

```
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
from bqplot import Tooltip
from bqplot import Scatter

fig = plt.figure(title='My title')

def_tt = Tooltip(fields=['name','nb'], formats = ['','.2f'], labels = ['Name','Nb'],show_labels = True )

chart = plt.scatter(df["a"],df["b"], colors = ['red'], tooltip = def_tt, stroke = 'red', unhovered_style ={'opacity':0.5})
fig
```

But the tooltips are empty, although the labels appear. I think I am missing something in the def_tt line, the fields parameters are probably uncorrect.

Answer (score 3):

With bqplot Tooltips, you can reference only the fields in the actual Mark. So something like this should work:

```
def_tt = Tooltip(fields=['index', 'x', 'y'], formats = ['','.2f'],)
```

If you want to pick up a different field from your dataframe, then you need to

1) create an output widget

2) define a function to run when you hover over a marker

3) set that output widget as the mark tooltip

4) Set that function to display your metadata in the output widget when you hover 
the mark.

```py
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
from bqplot import Tooltip
from bqplot import Scatter
from ipywidgets import Output

fig = plt.figure(title='My title')
out = Output(). # 1

def def_tt(_, event):  # 2
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
        print(df.loc[event['data']['index'], 'name'])

chart = plt.scatter(
    df["a"], df["b"], colors = ['red'], 
    tooltip = out, # 3
    stroke = 'red', unhovered_style ={'opacity':0.5}
)
chart.on_hover(def_tt) # 4
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! More complex than I thought but good anyway. I was able to add a second line in the tooltip by write ['name','id'] in the function def_tt.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new column in your dataframe, use it as a name and display the name in the tooltip:

```
fig = plt.figure()

def_tt = Tooltip(fields=['name'], show_labels=False)

df['labels'] = df.apply(lambda row: f'X: {row.x:%Y-%m-%d}, Y: {row.y:.2f}, Other Info: {row.custom_field}', axis=1)

scatt = plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, tooltip=def_tt,
                    # specify labels, but hide by default
                    names=df.labels, display_names=False)
fig
```

[image]

But it will not support rich formatting. Not even line breaks :(